# Example of set that fails to be a field in one specific axiom

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, field-theory

We know that a set $F$ together with two binary operations $+$ and $×$ is a field if and only if:

1. addition $+$ is associative;
2. addition $+$ is commutative;
3. addition $+$ has a neutral element $0$;
4. For every $a∈F$ there exists $b∈F$ such that $a+b=0$.
5. $×$ is associative;
6. $×$ is commutative;
7. $×$ distributes over $+$;
8. There is an element $1≠0$ such that $a×1=a$ for all $a∈F$;
9. For each $a∈F$, if $a≠0$ then there exists $x∈F$ such that $a×x=1$.

But I need to find an example of a set or structure that successfully fulfills all the requirements but the number $8$ (meaning there is not an element $1≠0$ such that $a×1=a$ for all $a∈F$). Any thoughts? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Note that axiom 9 generally won't make sense (or only hold because it is vacuously true) if you require that axiom 8 fails

Answer (score 3):

The trivial ring is the obvious example, i.e. $\left\{0\right\}$, with the obvious operations. In this ring, $0=1$, so there is no element not equal to $0$.

Comment: I think this is really the only example where axiom 9. can actually make sense

Answer (score 3):

The set $2\mathbb Z$ of all even integers with the usual addition and multiplication fulfills $1$ up to $7$.

Comment: It doesn't fulfill axiom $9$, though. OP wants one with everything but $8$.

Comment: @EeveeTrainer I see! Your example also fulfills $9$ by vacuity.